# Односвязный список в список

Tags: data-structures, c++, список

Всем привет. Объясните пожалуйста, как добавить один односвязный список в другой.
В одном списке хранится строка и число.
В другом списке должен быть первый список и ещё одна строка.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.
[image: тык]

Во втором списке значения переменных int первого списка разные.

P.S. Я студент, только учусь, поэтому всякие умнячие слова не используйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените указатель на следующий элемент последнего  элемента первого списка с NULL на адрес первого элемента второго списка.

**UPDATE**

Структуры данных для списка складов. Склад представлен списком товаров.

Списки односвязные. Элементы запоминаются в "порядке стека".

```
struct product {
  struct product *next;
  char *title;
  int  qty;
};

struct store {
  struct store *next;
  char *title;
  struct product *prod_list;
};
....
struct store *stores_list;

....
int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  // пусть каждый склад в своем файле
  // прочтем все склады
  struct store *stores_list = 0, *t;
  for (int i = 1; i < ac; i++) {
    t = get_store(av[i]);
    t->next = stores_list;
    stores_list = t;
  }
....
}
```

Чтение продуктов и построение их списка для каждого склада аналогично.

Для краткости все проверки опущены.

```
struct strore *get_store (char *fname)
{
    // допустим первая строка файла название склада, далее строки с товарами 
    // для простоты в формате NNN название товара
    FILE *in = fopen(fname, "r");
    char buf[4096];
    fgets(buf, 4096, in);
    struct store *store = (struct store *)malloc(sizeof(*store));
    store->title = strdup(buf);
    store->prod_list = 0;
    while(fgets(buf, 4096, in) != EOF) {
      char *p;
      struct product *p = (struct product *)malloc(sizeof(*p));
      p->qty = strtol(buf, &p, 10);
      p->title == strdup(p+1);  // по хорошему надо искать начало названия продукта "поточнее"
      p->next = store->prod_list;
      store->prod_list = p;
    }
    fclose(in);
    return store;
}
```

Код не поверял, но д.б. как-то так.

Comment: И что мне это даст? Разве это просто не соединит два списка в один больший?

Comment: Конечно, я именно так и понял Ваш вопрос.

Вы имели в виду что-то другое? Тогда выражайте свои мысли понятней.

Comment: Вот сейчас Вы нарисовали 2 картинки. 

Видимо верхняя, это первый список, элементы которого состоят из строки и числа.

Надо понимать, что нижняя это второй список, который Вас интересует и его элементы состоят из строки и первого списка. Так?

Уточните, Вам нужна *копия* первого списка в момент создания элемента второго списка или указатель на его первый элемент или что?

Во втором случае, что Вы хотите делать при удалении первого элемента первого списка?

Comment: @avp, так нужно ссылаться на сам список, а не на первый его элемент.

Comment: Извиняюсь, за неточную постановку.
Допустим, у меня имеется первый список (список1). В этом списке одно поле строка(строка1), другое цифра. Каждому названию - своё количество. Всё берётся из файла. Теперь, этот список надо занести в первый элемент, с ещё одним полей-строкой(строка2). Получнается, имени сопоставляется "склад".

Когда создаётся второй список, то меняется строка2, и частично меняются значения цифр из первого списка. Наименования остаются неизменными.

Получается, должно быть несколько складов. Кроме как вложенными списками, я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: @Alleshka, понял, Вам нужен список складов и каждый склад это список , например, продуктов.

Да, "вложенные списки" подойдут. На практике, возможно, лучше работать с двухсвязными списками. А с односвязными - см. UPDATE моего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

В первом списке Вы храните указатель на строку и инт, а во втором, помимо строки, Вам нужно добавить указатель на список.

Вот немного псевдокода.

```
// ваш первый список
class FirstListNode {
    FirstListNode *next;
    int intValue;
    char *stringValue;
};
class FirstList {
    FirstListNode *head;
    // methods
};

// ваш второй список
class SecondListNode {
    char *stringValue;
    FirstList *list;
};

class SecondList {
    SecondListNode *head;
};
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял Ваш вопрос.